# Subtracting amounts from wallets via SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

For the following set up (simplified):

```
transaction:
| transaction_id | account_id | transaction_amount |
| 1              | 1          | 80                 |
| 2              | 2          | 30                 |
| 3              | 3          | 66                 |

wallet:
| wallet_id | wallet_type |account_id | wallet_total |
| 1         | 1           | 1         | 50           |
| 2         | 2           | 1         | 30           |
| 3         | 2           | 2         | 40           |
| 4         | 2           | 3         | 100          |
| 5         | 1           | 3         | 25           |
```

I need to somehow subtract the transaction_amount from the wallets in wallet_type priority (in this case wallet_type 1 > wallet_type 2 but the priority can be different).

e.g.

Person 1 spends 80, has 2 wallets containing 50 and 30, first take out 50 from wallet 1 (wallet_type 1) then take out the remaining 30 in wallet 2 (wallet_type 2), leaving 0 in both wallets.

Person 2 spends 30, has 1 wallet (wallet_type 2) with 40, take 30 from it leaving 10

Person 3 spends 66, has 2 wallets containing 25 and 100, first take 25 out of wallet 1 (wallet_type 1) then take (66-25=) 41 from wallet 2 (wallet_type 2) leaving 0 in wallet 1 and 59 in wallet 2.

End result of the wallets after looping through the transactions should look like:

```
| wallet_id | wallet_type |account_id | wallet_total |
| 1         | 1           | 1         | 0            |
| 2         | 2           | 1         | 0            |
| 3         | 2           | 2         | 10           |
| 4         | 2           | 3         | 59           |
| 5         | 1           | 3         | 0            |
```

Im stuck on doing this for all cases, I can easily subtract it from scenario 2 because they only have 1 bucket to subtract from, but not sure how to approach subtracting it from one bucket then the other in one update.

If I could update the transaction table to reflect the amount after putting into one bucket that would be easier.. but I cant touch the transaction table.

I've also been able to "sort of" do it for scenario 1 by just seeing if their total wallet equates the transaction amount then zero-ing out their wallet.. but that doesn't work for all cases for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to do this in one update / script?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying this in postgres, is it easier to do in any other one?

Comment: It isn't a mater of which is easier. When you as an SQL question we need to know what variant is used so we can answer appropriately - always tag your sql questions with dbms

Comment: Apologies, I just meant that I wouldn't mind an answer in any other dbms as I could try to adapt it for my situation. I've updated the question tags now with postgresql-9.3